# error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, osx-lion

I upgraded to Mac OS X 10.7 from 10.6.
Then Mercurial does not work any more, and when I reinstalled Mercurial the error message jumped out like below:

```
$ sudo pip install -U Mercurial
```

**First Error lines below:**

```
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Headers/ApplicationServices.h:20,
                 from mercurial/osutil.c:523:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:21:19: error: AE/AE.h: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:25:35: error: CarbonCore/CarbonCore.h: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:29:35: error: OSServices/OSServices.h: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:33:43: error: CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:37:33: error: CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:41:43: error: LaunchServices/LaunchServices.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SearchKit.h:30,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:45,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Headers/ApplicationServices.h:20,
                 from mercurial/osutil.c:523:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKDocument.h:20:35: error: CoreFoundation/CFBase.h: No such file or directory
```

**THOUSANDS OF LINES ERROS OMISSION HERE...**

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Headers/ATSTypes.h:242: error: declaration for parameter ‘FMFontDirectoryFilter’ but no such parameter

mercurial/osutil.c:580: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input

error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/patto/dev/django/hg_fuwo/build/Mercurial/build/Mercurial/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-ZYZ6B4-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1 in /Users/patto/dev/django/hg_fuwo/build/Mercurial/build/Mercurial
Storing complete log in /Users/patto/Library/Logs/pip.log
patto@mac:Mercurial > hg summary
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/hg", line 4, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: mercurial==1.9
```

I searched several solutions but none of them works:

- Use python setup.py install .   Not work!
- Install [Kenneth Reitz's nice package](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer) . Not work!

Are there any more solutions?

Comment: Where are you downloading the source code from? It looks like a compilation error to me.

Comment: Is that all of the compile errors? Can you make sure you've copy+pasted *all* of them in?

Comment: @DavidWolever That is just the key parts of error logs. There are thousands of lines that I just pasted those.

Comment: @Blender The source code of what? Mercurial or Python?

Comment: Then please paste the *very first* line that caused an error, along with the five or six lines above and below it. This is likely an error caused by a missing dependency of header file… But it's impossible to tell what that dependency or file is without the first error.

Comment: Of Mercurial. Python should be the default OSX install, right?

Comment: @DavidWolever I have pasted the head parts of install information.

Comment: @Blender Yes, Python is the default one, while Mercurial is installed via Pip, I think pip downloaded the source from PyPI by default, right?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. By "very first line that caused an error", I mean "the very first error line". The warning lines can (most likely) be safely ignored. You'll be able to find it because it'll be the first line that has `error:` in it.

Comment: @DavidWolever I am sorry, this time it's OK :)